# Cutting holes into a flat surface

Tags: modeling

So, I have this square, and I would like to add a lot of little holes to it.  Something like this: 
[image]

Say, ports from a wire or something.  But, alas, when I try to move the port back into the square object: 
[image]
The original face of the square remains stoically in place.  How to I put round holes in a flat face?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to go about this, most common and easiest is to use a boolean modifier. Select the plane and add a *Boolean* modifier to it, In hte *Object* field, select the object you want to stamp holes with (ie some cylinders joined together) and change the *Operation* to *Difference*. Next apply the modifer, delete or hide the cyclinders then <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and box select the botton half of the mesh that protruded down and delete these.

[image]

If your mesh has thickness, you can just delete or hide the cylinders after applying the boolean modifier.

[image]

You can also further read up on some more techniques here http://www.blendernation.com/2013/07/14/8-methods-of-cutting-holes/.