# How to mask off part of image plane

Tags: masking

In my scene, I have an image plane with a picture of some kitchen tiles. I also have a cube which has been UV unwrapped and has the same texture as the image plane, but positioned so that the front face of the cube fits to one of the tiles.

I want to have the front face which has also been separated by selection so that I can open it like a lid and 'see' inside the cube.

The problem is that the image plane cuts into the cube. How do I mask the area where I want to see through to the cube behind?

[image: image plane]
Image plane

[image: scene]
Scene

Please also look at my [BLEND FILE](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32925) if you can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cutting holes into a flat surface](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18732/cutting-holes-into-a-flat-surface)

Answer (score 1):

## Materials only solution

1. Create a cube
2. name it *cookie cutter*  (Optional)
3. Give it this material:
   [image]
4. Apply this material:
   [image]
   to the *background plane*, and position *cookie cutter* to make the hole.

**Note:** When the camera looks through the cookie cutter at the plane, the plane will be transparent, so make the cookie cutter narrow. It may also be affected by other objects, so be careful.

## Texture + Material Solution

1. Apply this material to the *background plane*
   [image]
2. In the top image node, give it a black and white image, where it is white, there will be a hole.

**Note:** This is very robust, but can be a huge pain if you start moving your objects.

Comment: Texture+Material Solution: If your render engine is EeVee, this won't work unless you have your Blend Mode set to Alpha Blend in your material settings.