# How precisely repeat shapes?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Hi I want to find easiest way how to model a circle with circular holes:

[image]

The holes should be precisely positioned (e.g. every 15°).

Comment: I'd use an array modifier

Comment: on what object ? And how would you create the first object? Assuming I want a hole every 15°.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Model the circle
2. Add cylinder (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), then enter edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. Scale the cylinder (<kbd>S</kbd>) so it has the same radius as desired for the holes
4. Move it over on the X or Y axis so it intersects the circle (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>)
5. Exit edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
6. Add an empty (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and rotate it 15° on the Z (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>15</kbd>)
7. Add an array modifier to the cylinder
8. Disable *relative offset* and enable *object offset*
9. Specify the empty as the offset object in the array modifier
   <sub>Note: You can press <kbd>E</kbd> while hovering over the object selection box to pick an object by clicking in the 3D view</sub>
10. Increase the count until there are cylinders all around the circle
11. [Add a boolean modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18732/599) to the circle
12. Specify the cylinder object as the boolean target
13. Set the boolean operation to *difference*
14. Apply the boolean modifier
15. Delete now unneeded cylinder object and empty

[image]

Comment: @JaroslavKotowski Applying the boolean modifier is optional, and you don't have to delete the repeated circle, you can hide it until you are ready to finalize. This lets you see the holes without committing so early.

Comment: This looks very much like one of my answers, the number list for the steps, and a gif at the bottom. I guess if gandalf does it, I must be doing something right. :)

Comment: @David XD I've done it with the gif on top before, but I think this is the first time I've put the gif below..