# What is the most efficient way to apply a modification to all faces of a regular object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have a cylinder that is being modified (for 3D printing, I'm loosely following [this advice](https://makezine.com/2015/07/22/tips-3d-printing-press-fit-parts/) .)
[image]

As you can see, I have one segment of the cylinder modified.  However, I'm wondering if anyone knows of any good way to quickly apply these modification to all of the segments, rather than hand editing the next 5 of them?

You can get the blend [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/f723c99cdf8d4daf80b2839b08011e1f).

Comment: Thanks for the image, but I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to add the rectangular cutout to the rest of the sides of the hexagon?

Comment: Yes, basically.  I did this with a series of extrusions, the intersections, the deleting needless faces, but I imagine there are actually numerous ways of going about this; most of them present at least one thing I think I can do but don't know how.

Comment: Perhaps an Array Modifier would do it for you, like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30472/how-precisely-repeat-shapes