# How can I open a circular window in a cylinder?

Tags: modeling

Just like in this picture.. This is a cylinder with a circular window.
Please notice that the frame is evenly distributed along the cylinder and I want to achive the same result, any tips?

[image]

Comment: You can start [cutting a hole in the surface](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object), or [like this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18732/cutting-holes-into-a-flat-surface) and then [subdividing mesh keeping hard edges](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Answer (score 5):

1. Start by adding a circle where the window will go.
2. <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> to extrude then scale the circle giving making a (still flat) window frame.
   [image: modeling the window frame]
3. Add a *[Shrinkwrap](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier)* modifier then a *[Solidify](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier)* modifier to the window frame.  Set the Shrinkwrap modifier *Target* to your main cylinder object. Set the *Mode* to *Project* and choose the correct axis for your object (in my example it is the positive Y).
   The Solidify modifier is simple, give your window frame the *Thickness* you want, and set the *Offset* to 1.
   [image: modifier settings]
4. Last step is to cut a circular hole in your mesh for the window. You can do that with a boolean modifier, knife project (how I do it in the gif), or manually adding loop cuts and deleting faces to make a hole. The answers to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7928/2217) do a good job of explaining the processes.

Animated gif of the entire process.
[image: animated gif]