# the fastest way to hole curved side of a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Does anyone knows the fastest and easiest way to hole the curved side of a cylinder in blender 2.8? thanks!

Comment: Please add what you mean by *hole a cylinder* - cutting a hole?

Comment: you have a lot of tutorials about this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQA6-3UECoY

Comment: yes, this is the one I was watching right now, just wanted to know if since this video is almost 3 years old we had a new magic and faster way in 2.8 you guys could recommend. thanks though!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/how-can-i-open-a-circular-window-in-a-cylinder and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh