# Boolean cut with cylinders cross

Tags: modifiers

First of sorry for my english. I need some help here guys. I'm trying to boolean cut (operation: difference) a hole on a pipe-like shape with cylinder but doesn't work. I made two kind of this pipe-like shape one from a plane and another from a cylinder. Both failed.

Here's a screenshot of what i'm trying to do.
[image]

Here's a link to the file on my gdrive:
[cylinders_boolean.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sPsTTicDC2tb9EqBvmNNEaZu6TXwDwlk)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/how-can-i-open-a-circular-window-in-a-cylinder/46529#46529 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-hole-into-an-object/30997#30997

Comment: The answers from the links you mentioned can't be applied to my case as my pipe has to sides to be cut. I'v tried both top answers and they don't work as i expected. But [Nick's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/38159/nick) answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that might be affecting you.

Firstly your model is extremely small (switch to camera view to see how small it is). This will affect the default Boolean modifier settings, which has certain error thresholds. Try scaling everything up about 10 times.

In each Boolean modifier you need to select one of the smaller cylinders as the thing to work with.

Also, the smaller cylinders are not hidden by default so even if the modifier is successful you'll still see the cylinders in place unless you hide them (which you can do from the outliner in top-right).

Here's your scene after I did these things:

[image: Success]

You may also need to hide the cylinders for render as shown here - you can do this from *Object Properties > Visibility* or you can add this option to the outliner for quick access as shown below. (Thanks to Nathan Hild in the comments)

[image: Disable in render]

Comment: Also don't forget to set the two small cylinders to not render else they will show up in the render but not in the viewport. Go to the object properties > Visibility > Uncheck "Show in render"

Comment: Thanks Nathan, thought I'd done that but was looking at the wrong outliner column - added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys it worked well but don't forget to apply the scale too. I guess size does matter in blender.